# Thermal Printer API for endicia

Tags: php

We would like to know that - how can we print shipping label through thermal printer using endicia api - we have tried ZPLII and EPL2 - basically we are trying to call endicia API form our site and trying to print label on our server - we are getting image in decode format - how can we print it through thermal printer -  We are using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Try using jZebra http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/ it is designed to interface between a web page and the OS

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to use shiprush endicia (with shiprush sdk), I send it an XML block, it runs the endicia shipment and sends the epl to the printer directly, so I don't get in the middle of the label print.